# I can't test the INSTALL_REFERER broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-broadcast

First of all sorry for my bad English, I am improving it.

I am trying to test the INSTALL_REFERER boradcast but I can't make it work.

My package:

```
es.beedroid.beebubble
```

The receiver in my manifest is:

```
<receiver
        android:name="es.beedroid.beebubble.Load$InstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

To test that receiver I make this:

```
static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {

    Intent i = new Intent("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER");
//      i.setPackage("es.beedroid.beebubble");

    i.putExtra("referrer", "&huevos=hola");
    context.sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

But when I launch the app I get the following error:

```
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate     receiver es.beedroid.beebubble.Load$InstallReferrerReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: es.beedroid.beebubble.Load$InstallReferrerReceiver
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1874)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:156)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1050)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: es.beedroid.beebubble.Load$InstallReferrerReceiver
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1440)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1865)
04-04 12:46:05.432: E/AndroidRuntime(20996):    ... 10 more
```

Why? Is there another way to test that function? I tried to test it with adb but it doesn't work (it never passes by the receiver) .

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n     es.beedroid.beebubble/.com.beedroid.activities.Load$InstallReferrerReceiver --es "referrer"     "utm_source=test_source&utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **./** to adb and use the below

```
./adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n es.beedroid.beebubble/es.beedroid.beebubble.Load$InstallReferrerReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=test_source&utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name"
```

Also there were white spaces which I have removed and your path said

`.com.beedroid.activities.Load$InstallReferrerReceiver`

which I feel should be

`es.beedroid.beebubble.Load$InstallReferrerReceiver`

Let me know if it does work, coz I debugged using the same way and it did.

Note - App should **NOT** be running when you hit this from terminal.

Happy coding:)

Comment: Cant check it , I dont have more access to that code anymore sorry :S

Comment: Ohh :( let this be reference to others who face the same :)